# How to assign the shared_ptr object to the function of type raw pointer using C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am creating the shared_ptr in a function and returning raw pointer from that function.
To get the underlying raw pointer from the shared_ptr I am using .get()

If i am using the raw pointer in a function and assigning to the function of type raw pointer it is working without any issue.
But if i create the shared_ptr and while returning, it is calling the destructor and deleting the memory assigned to the object and crashing.

How to assign the shared_ptr object to the function of type raw pointer?

```
CMyClass::CMyClass()
{
}

CMyClass::~CMyClass()
{
}

CMyClass* CreateClassInstance()
{
std::shared_ptr<CMyClass> l_MyClassInterface = std::make_shared<CMyClass>();
return l_MyClassInterface.get();
}

CMyClass* CreateClassInstance()
{
CMyClass* l_MyClassInterface = new CMyClass();
return l_MyClassInterface;
}

auto l_pMyClassInterface = CreateClassInstance();
```

Comment: You should return the `shared_ptr`, not a raw pointer. Returning a raw pointer defeats the whole purpose of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: The non-owning raw pointer becomes a dangling pointer if the last federated ownership shared_ptr is destructed.  You need to ensure that the shared_ptr object outlives the use of the non-owning raw pointer.

Comment: The call you are looking for is named `release()`, but I agree with @user17732522, that doing that defeats the entire purpose of using a `shared_ptr`

Comment: I would have `CreateClassInstance()` return a `unique_ptr` instead.  A `unique_ptr` can be moved into a `shared_ptr` if needed later.  You should generally stay away from `shared_ptr` unless you *really* need shared ownership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what @user17732522 said.

In the code as written, `l_MyClassInterface` is going out of scope when your first version of `CreateClassInstance` returns, taking your newly created object with it.  When you return a `shared_ptr`, as opposed to the pointer returned by `get()`, the mechanism that it uses to keep track of the reference count for your object kicks in and stops that from happening. (Well, in principle.  In practise, copy elision usually / always ensures that the `shared_ptr` created by `make_shared` is returned directly to the caller, but that's a detail.)

The other (inferior) solution would be to return the pointer returned by `new` directly and assign it to a `shared_ptr` in the caller.  But that is error-prone, and not recommended.